# Withdrawing from an election and re-nominating allows nominees to invisibly push themselves to the top of the candidate list

Tags: bug, election, nominations

According to [election notice](https://stackoverflow.com/election/14?tab=nomination) on nomination phase:

> All nominees are displayed in reverse order of nomination.

But if someone withdraw yourself and apply again (the nominee notice even remains, so the whole process looks like the nominee editing) then this person's nominee will be displayed at the top of the list. So you can withdraw and apply back several times to became on the top of the list.

I expect that the relative position of the nominee remains the same as on the first nomination attempt.

Comment: In the primary and election phases, nominees are in random order. Realistically, this would only affect public commenting in the nomination phase.

Comment: Is withdrawing and re-nominating even a thing? If yes, then fix that.

Comment: wouldn't people notice and point it out. You wouldn't get elected if you'd pulled that kind of stunt would you?

Comment: @RobertLongson you're right, in case of abusing (several time without other reason). But when it's done by accident (or by nominee's doubts: withdraw and reapply) I think it should not shed some shadow on nominee. That's why I suggest to preserve the relative order as it was on the first nomination (to avoid different interpretations).

Comment: @rene it's not clear for me what you mean by "even a thing" in this case. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Idioms by The Free Dictionary: [Is that (even) a thing?](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Is+that+(even)+a+thing%3F)

Comment: In this case, I think the bigger issue is that a user whose nomination was withdrawn by a CM was able to renominate, as @rene's comment points out.

Comment: (I don't think the ordering of candidates during the Nominations phase really matters much on its own – I assume newer candidates are sorted first just so it's easy to see what new nominations there have been since you last checked the page, and edited/resubmitted nominations would still make sense to display as "new" since something will have changed in the nomination statement/questionnaire since it was previously submitted.)

Comment: @V2Blast changing the statement doesn't make reordering, only withdrawal with the following reapplying. No need to change anything at all.

Comment: @V2Blast I thought the candidates are sorted by newest first in the nomination phase so that the newer nominations get a better chance to be read and commented on.